# How to dynamically add slices to a disk image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable

Hi I am new to Android and I am currently experimenting with some Android features.
So I wanted to find a way to add flexibly add slices to a disk image (could be a pie chart or a roulette wheel). I have done some research on this topic, [Drawable Resources | Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html). If I wanted to insert a slice dynamically, I think the `InsetDrawable` method would best suit my situation. So that a bitmap would not be recreated every time the image changes. I have also gone over some tutorial on how to change Cartesian coordinates into Polar coordinates [Android SDK: Creating a Rotating Dialer](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/). I was hoping to combine the `InsetDrawable` method with the polar coordinates to achieve this function. So I was wondering if can anyone tell me whether or not my thoughts are feasible?

A sample of the image that I would like to get is shown below:

[image]

Instead of having 6 slices, the user could add more elements to populate the disk to make it 8 or 10 slices, or remove slices from the disk.

It would be great if anyone can share a link to some of the related topics or tutorials as such.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is that you exactly want? If you want to dynamically add a slice every time you click a button, all you have to do is arrange the 6 slices in the form of a circle in the xml as 6 ImageViews. You will have to make these ImageViews invisible initially. And inside the onClick function of the button you make the ImageViews visible one by one.

Comment: I was thinking if it's possible to let the user decide how many slices they want and they can change the number of slices as well. As a result, a fixed number of `ImageView` would not be in the XML file. Your suggestion matches exactly what I have in mind if the above approach would not work out. Love to hear you advice on this. Cheers :)

Comment: Assuming that you'd know the maximum number of slices the user could choose, you could first divide the image into that number of slices. Then arrange it in the same way as I mentioned above. Depending on the user input, you just have to make the respective ImageView/ImageViews visible inside the on click of the button. i know it is difficult and complicated. But that is the only way I believe it can be done.

Comment: No, actually, this is quite simple, which is what I have right now. What I was pursuing was to let the user decide how much slice they want. So setting a fixed amount in the xml isn't very helpful (some user may want 6 slices 60 degree arc each, some user may want 12 slices 30 degrees each). Thanks anyways, I'll keep searching for answers.